# Alias to user directory

Tags: apache-2.2, alias

In Apache2 I would like to dynamically Alias urls like this:

`Alias /foo /etc/myapp/foo/www`

`Alias /bar /etc/myapp/bar/www`

`Alias /noob /etc/myapp/noob/www`

and so forth, where /xxx is any existing directory under /etc/myapp that contains a subdirectory 'www'. Is this possible in Apache2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on what you want, you can do it with [mass virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html), [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html), or simple shell script:

```
for d in `ls -l /etc/myapp | grep '^d' | awk '{ print $9 }'`; do 
    if [ `ls -l /etc/myapp/"$d" | grep '^d' | grep -c www` -eq 1 ]; then 
        echo "Alias /$d /etc/myapp/$d/www" >> /path/to/httpd.conf
    fi 
done
```

Could you please explain your situation a little more?